# For what sort of volume mounting errors will Docker fail silently?

Tags: docker

I have a docker run command of the following form:

```
docker run --add-host test.jimvanfleet.com:127.0.0.1            -v /home/myuser/etc/certs:/etc/httpd/certs   -v /home/myuser/etc/site:/etc/httpd/site -v /home/myuser/etc/conf/my.conf:/tmp/my.conf --name=https_proxy --rm bigfleet/https_proxy:master
```

This command (as I expect) yields a container running an httpd process in the foreground.

This command:

```
docker run --add-host test.jimvanfleet.com:127.0.0.1            -v /home/myuser/etc/certs:/etc/httpd/certs   -v /home/myuser/etc/site:/etc/httpd/site -v /home/myuser/etc/conf/my.conf:/etc/httpd/conf.d/my.conf --name=https_proxy --rm bigfleet/https_proxy:master
```

will exit immediately with an error status code, with no logs that I see.  I've only changed the target directory inside the container for the `my.conf` file.

There is no change if I run the second command with `--privileged`, since I am not running the container as `root` and I'm attempting to mount the volume to a directory that can only be written to by `root`.  Running the same command as the `root` user also doesn't work, immediately exiting with exit code 1.  What can I do to further debug this problem?

Comment: You can perform `docker logs id` to check what's going wrong. I would also try to `docker exec` inside your first running container to check the permissions of the /etc/httpd/conf.d/ folder + does it exist

Comment: The logs show only a "Set the 'ServerName' directive" warning.  The directory does exist, and so does the error even after a chmod 777 to the /etc/httpd/conf.d directory in the Dockerfile

Comment: What if you don't try to mount the volume but just create the image + container and perform a `docker cp` with a file from the host to that file. (also go inside your container and check the path).